# Adding column in already created table in postgresql,make it lower

Tags: postgresql

I have already created table .I want to add one more string column into it.

```
ALTER TABLE test."persons" 
ADD COLUMN RightName VARCHAR(150);
```

Column get added in table with name rightname.

Why this is so,why not RightName?Any thing I missed.
Do I need to specify length for varchar column.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS  - unquoted identifiers in SQL should be folded to upper case according to the SQL standard. Postgres decided to fold them lowercase.

Comment: How to do change this now. I want column name like this only 'RightName'

Comment: The usual naming conventions in Postgres is to use snake case `right_name`

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
ALTER TABLE test."persons" 
ADD COLUMN "RightName" VARCHAR(150);
```

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL it's better to use `"RightName"` when u adding a new column to already created table by a SQL code (use quotes)

Or u can add `"RightName"` column in *properties* of your table by hands